# Redimensionar imagen con angular 7 para subir a Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, typescript, angular7

Estoy subiendo imagenes a el storage de Firebase pero algunas imagenes estan muy pesadas quiero optimizar esto. Las apis que he visto redimensionan a un ancho y alto específico pero mis imagenes no todas son perfectas para realizarlo así.

Trabaje en larabel el siguiente código para realizar lo que quiero para mantener la simetría de mi imagen:

```
$file = $request->file($name2);
$image = Image::make($file);
$imageW = $image->width() / 3;
$imageH = $image->height() / 3;
$image->resize($imageW, $imageH, function ($constraint) {
  $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```

y obtenía mi imagen redimensionada sin perder calidad ni pedazos de la misma.

Que API o puedo traducir a angular 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a las extensiones que Google Firebase te ofrece, entre ellas ya viene una extensión para redimensionar imágenes, así no reinventas la rueda y usas buenas prácticas de desarrollo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]